# Should I throw away my wheels after they bumped in the sidewalks?

Tags: wheels

Rear right wheel
[image]

The black liquid is traces of WD-40

Front right wheel
[image]

This occured after driving at 30 km/h and bumping in a part of the sidewalk that was going into the street.

Does this damage need me any repair before I can put new tires on the rear wheel ?

Should I repair / change the front wheel ? (still up and running)

CONCLUSION :

- 1 found a decent unused alloy wheel + tyre (new) for 80$, and replaced the rear wheel, that would not fill with one of those "tire repair kit" pressurized foam bottles.
- the front wheel's damage has not changed the shape of the part that is in responsible of the sealing of the tubeless tyre, so no change needed for the moment ! :-)

Comment: Wow.  That had to have been quite a ride!  I've smoked a couple curbs in my day with lower profile tires and have yet to damage a rim.  I can't imagine how violent an impact you had!

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: not so violent to be honest. Just was driving at about 30km / h and the border of the sidewalks was kind of coming into the street... Just rolled over the edgy part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need to have them either changed or fixed. Fixing may cost as much as replacement wheels considering they are steel, but I haven't priced either lately, so getting them trued might be cheaper. The tires probably will not hold air with them the way they are, so you don't have much of a choice. Besides, even if they do, they will thump like a big dog going down the road. It will drive you nuts. Get them fixed or replaced, but they won't work like they are, that's for sure.

Comment: @SkippyFastol ... No worries. I feel your pain. Please, if this answer suits you, chose it as such.

Comment: Yes, replace them. If there is ANY sidewall damage, replace the them. The "goo in a can" does NOT work on sidewalls, and driving with a hole in your sidewall is very dangerous